# identifier 'DBMS_CDC_PUBLISH.CREATE_CHANGE_SET' must be declared

Tags: oracle-11g, oracle-sql-developer, change-data-capture

I am using oracle 11g express edition and I am getting the below error when trying to create a change set.

Error report:

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_CDC_PUBLISH.CREATE_CHANGE_SET' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

I know CDC is desupported in later versions of oracle but I think it is supported here.

Can anyone help please?

I've tried to explicitly grant permission to the `SYSTEM` user with

```
grant execute on DBMS_CDC_PUBLISH to SYSTEM;
```

But I get

```
ORA-04042: procedure, function, package, or package body does not exist
```

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. Could you possibly post the statement you are trying to execute? Hit [edit] and add to your question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted on Stack Overflow and has an accepted answer. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64640874/1820861)

Answer (score 2):

### Verifying Packages

To verify that you indeed do have the required packages in Oracle run the following statement:

```
set pages 50
set lines 230
column owner format a20
column object_name format a30 


SELECT DISTINCT Owner, Object_Type, Object_Name FROM DBA_Objects_AE
     WHERE Owner IN (
       'SYS', 'OUTLN', 'SYSTEM', 'CTXSYS', 'DBSNMP',
       'LOGSTDBY_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ORDSYS',
       'ORDPLUGINS', 'OEM_MONITOR', 'WKSYS', 'WKPROXY',
       'WK_TEST', 'WKUSER', 'MDSYS', 'LBACSYS', 'DMSYS',
       'WMSYS', 'OLAPDBA', 'OLAPSVR', 'OLAP_USER',
       'OLAPSYS', 'EXFSYS', 'SYSMAN', 'MDDATA',
       'SI_INFORMTN_SCHEMA', 'XDB', 'ODM')

     AND Object_Type IN ('PACKAGE')
     AND Object_Name like 'DBMS_CDC%'
     ORDER BY Owner, Object_Type, Object_Name
```

This should return something like this:

> ```
> OWNER                OBJECT_TYPE             OBJECT_NAME                   
> -------------------- ----------------------- ------------------------------
> SYS                  PACKAGE                 DBMS_CDC_DPUTIL               
> SYS                  PACKAGE                 DBMS_CDC_EXPDP                
> SYS                  PACKAGE                 DBMS_CDC_EXPVDP               
> SYS                  PACKAGE                 DBMS_CDC_IMPDP                
> SYS                  PACKAGE                 DBMS_CDC_IMPDPV               
> SYS                  PACKAGE                 DBMS_CDC_IPUBLISH             
> SYS                  PACKAGE                 DBMS_CDC_ISUBSCRIBE           
> SYS                  PACKAGE                 DBMS_CDC_PUBLISH              
> SYS                  PACKAGE                 DBMS_CDC_SUBSCRIBE            
> SYS                  PACKAGE                 DBMS_CDC_SYS_IPUBLISH         
> SYS                  PACKAGE                 DBMS_CDC_UTILITY              
>
> 11 rows selected.
> ```

### Package Parameters

If all is well, then you can run the following statement to determine the required inputs for `DBMS_CDC_PUBLISH.CREATE_CHANGE_SET`:

```
set pages 50
set lines 250
column object_info format a200
    
     
select ao.object_type
  ||' '|| ao.owner ||'.'|| ao.object_name
  || case when ap.procedure_name is not null then
    '.'|| ap.procedure_name
    || case when count(aa.argument_name) > 0 then
      '('|| listagg(aa.argument_name, ',')
        within group (order by position) ||')'
    end
  end as object_info
from all_objects ao
left join all_procedures ap
on ap.owner = ao.owner
and ap.object_name = ao.object_name
and ap.object_id = ao.object_id
left join all_arguments aa
on aa.owner = ap.owner
and aa.object_name = ap.procedure_name
and aa.object_id = aa.object_id
and aa.subprogram_id = ap.subprogram_id
where ao.owner in (
  'SYS', 'OUTLN', 'SYSTEM', 'CTXSYS', 'DBSNMP',
  'LOGSTDBY_ADMINISTRATOR', 'ORDSYS',
  'ORDPLUGINS', 'OEM_MONITOR', 'WKSYS', 'WKPROXY',
  'WK_TEST', 'WKUSER', 'MDSYS', 'LBACSYS', 'DMSYS',
  'WMSYS', 'OLAPDBA', 'OLAPSVR', 'OLAP_USER',
  'OLAPSYS', 'EXFSYS', 'SYSMAN', 'MDDATA',
  'SI_INFORMTN_SCHEMA', 'XDB', 'ODM')
and ao.object_type in ('PACKAGE', 'TYPE')
and ao.object_name like 'DBMS_CDC_PUBLISH%'
and ap.procedure_name like 'CREATE_CHANGE_SET%'

group by ao.object_type, ao.owner, ao.object_name, ap.procedure_name,
  ao.object_id, ap.subprogram_id
order by ao.owner, ao.object_type, ao.object_name, ap.procedure_name;
```

This should return:

> ```
> OBJECT_INFO                                                                                                                                                                                             
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> PACKAGE SYS.DBMS_CDC_PUBLISH.CREATE_CHANGE_SET(CHANGE_SET_NAME,DESCRIPTION,CHANGE_SOURCE_NAME,STOP_ON_DDL,BEGIN_DATE,END_DATE)                                                                          
> 1 row selected.
> ```

## Isues

If you don't get a result, then you are possibly running a version of Oracle that doesn't support the package or you don't have sufficient privileges.

### CDC Edition Support

...in synchronous mode is available in Oracle Standard Edition:

> Change Data Capture comes packaged with the appropriate Oracle drivers already installed with which you can implement either asynchronous or synchronous data capture. The **synchronous mode** of Change Data Capture is included with the **Standard Edition**, but the **asynchronous mode requires** you have the **Enterprise Edition**.

## Reference Material

- [How to get a list with description of all dba packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545184/how-to-get-a-list-with-description-of-all-dba-packages) (Stack Overflow)
- [Introduction to Oracle Supplied PL/SQL Packages & Types](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/intro.htm#ARPLS001)  (Oracle | Docs)
- [DBMS_CDC_PUBLISH](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_cdcpub.htm#i80091) (Oracle | Docs)
- [Change Data Capture](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/cdc.htm) (Oracle | Docs)

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64640107/identifier-dbms-cdc-publish-create-change-set-must-be-declared/64640874#64640874

Same answer:

The problem is that you are using Express Edition, which does not include Change Data Capture functionality.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/license.112/e18068/toc.htm#XELIC101